Spring Boot: Scheduled tasks stop working suddenly
I have a Spring-Boot App (3.2.5) with some components and @Scheduled methods.
At some time all these tasks (no matter if fixedRate, fixedDelay or cron) stop working and the CPU of the java process is at 100% (not the whole CPU put 1 kernel).
Any idea what this is or I can find out the cause of that??

Execution occurs in a single thread, and if the previous task takes too long, it may block other tasks until it completes. Could that be the problem?

But should the other tasks not start again it that long task finished? Or are they gone forever? What I see is that they never start again.

Normally, after a long-running task is completed, other tasks should be able to continue. If not executed there may be other problems
